# I am having two forms and two controller now i want to check the status of those two forms in different controllers in angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="firstController">
   <form name=form1>
    //there are some required fields here
    <input type="button" ng-click="submit1(form1)"/>
   </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="secondController">
    <form name=form2>
       // there are some required fields here
       <input type="button" ng-click="submit2(form2)"/>
       //I can check the status in controller by "$scope.form2.$valid" here
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="checkStatus">
     <input type="button" ng-click="submit3(form1,form2)"/>
     //how can i check here
  </div>
</div>
```

As in above code i am having different controllers and different forms associated to it. there is one section where i need to check all the forms status
As i am new to angular js can any one help me out, how to figure this out. any help may be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have parent form. If any of it's children forms will be invalid, then parent will be invalid too:

```
<div ng-form="parentForm">
    ... two forms inside
</div>
```

Then check `parentForm.$valid`

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/Lv4hoxs1/2/).

Just change `form` to `ng-form`. And added parent `ng-form` as @karaxuna say.

```js
function MyCtrl1($scope) {
  $scope.test1 = "12";
};

function MyCtrl2($scope) {
  $scope.test2 = "34";
};

function MyCtrl3($scope) {};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-form="parentForm">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
      <div ng-form="form1">
        <input required ng-model="test1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
      <div ng-form="form2">
        <input required ng-model="test2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl3">
      <div ng-form="form3">
        <input required ng-model="test3">
        <pre>parentForm.$invalid = {{parentForm.$invalid}}
        parentForm.$valid = {{parentForm.$valid}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using JQuery

`angular.element('#firstController').scope().submit2()`
you can invoke anywhere

> Using Angular

```
<div id="main" ng-controller="main">  
<div id="firstController"  ng-controller="firstController">
<form ></form>
</div>

<div id="secondController" ng-controller="secondController">
<form ></form>
</div>    
 </div>
```

Calling second controller function from first controller

`$scope.$parent.submit2()`
before you use above you should even set it to parent scope.